# How to treat -classpath attribute Java 10 in JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, java-10

My project is highly dependable on JNI to communicate with C code. I have been using Java 8 for years now. I decided to upgrade to Java 10 but I have faced a problem with JNI implementation.

I have some imported libraries in the Java class that contains the native methods as follows:

```
import com.abc.repair.Results;

public class DataSupport {

    public native Results getPartResults(String x);
    public native Results getItemResults(String x);
}
```

Java 8 Implementation:

```
javah -jni -classpath ../lib/Results.jar com.abc.jni.DataSupport
```

Java 10 implementation:

```
javac -h . ../build/com/abc/jni/DataSupport.java
```

Java 10's implementation works great if there is no import from any other library. However it fails to build complaining about `com.abc.repair.Results` does not exist when here is any import. Adding class path the same way used in Java 8 did not solve the problem.

How can I use `-classpath` or what is the alternative to it in Java 10?

Comment: Did you try adding the jar to the `modulepath` instead?

Answer (score 2):

You must specify **sourcepath**. In your case, it would look like

```
javac -h . -sourcepath ../build ../build/com/abc/jni/DataSupport.java
```

Comment: It actually worked with javac -h . -classpath ../build ../build/com/abc/jni/DataSupport.java. I just had to put the "." (the current directory) before -classpath attribute. Your hint helped. Thank you!

Comment: That `.` is where to store the generated header